# Sphere of radius $x$ and volume $V(x)$. How to find $y(x)$ such that $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} V(x) y(x) = k$?

Tags: limits

So I am trying to find out which $y(x)$ functions can solve the following limit.

$$
\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \sqrt{\frac{4 \pi x^3}{3}} y(x) = k
$$

The problem came up when I was trying to show that for a particular scalar field $\rho(\tau)$ for $\tau=(r,\theta,\phi)$ expanded as a set of radial polynomials orthonormal in a 3-ball of radius $x$ times orthonormal real spherical harmonics, the integral of the field in the ball converges as $x$ approaches infinity.

Doing the math it turns out that the integral equals $\sqrt{V(x)} c_0$, where $V$ is the volume of the ball of radius $x$ and $c_0$ is the coefficient of the very first term in the expansion and I end up with tye limit above.

This tells me that $y(x)$ must have a particular form for the integral to converge, and the convergence of the integral has physical significance.

There is the basic polynomial solution $y_0(x) = a x^{-\frac{3}{2}} + b x^{-1} + c x^{-\frac{1}{2}} + d$ for which

$$
\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \sqrt{\frac{4 \pi x^3}{3}} y_0(x) = a \sqrt{\frac{4 \pi}{3}} = a \sqrt{V(1)}
$$

So for the case where the limit equation holds we have that any polynomial of that form is a solution, provided $a = k\sqrt{\frac{1}{V(1)}}$.

But the $y_0(x)$ is the easy case, I was wondering if there were different (hopefully weirder) kinds of functions $y(x)$ for which that limit is true, or if one can prove that polynomials are the only way to go.

P.S. forgive my mathematical ignorance if this is a trivial matter =P.

Comment: essentialy every function of the form $ f(x)= a x^{-3/2}+g(x)$ where $g(x)\ll x^{-3/2}$ will do the job

Comment: It seems to me that your $y_0(x)$ doesn't work unless $b=c=d=0$ since $\sqrt{4\pi x^3/3}x^{-1}\rightarrow\infty$ for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any function of the form $y(x)=cx^{-3/2}+g(x)$ where
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{g(x)}{x^{-3/2}}= 0$$
would work out. For instance $g(x)=e^{-x}$, $g(x)=x^{-2}+x^{-3}+3x^{-5}$... You could use $y(x)=x^{-3/2}h(x)$ where $h(x)\rightarrow 0$. There really is a lot of freedom.

Comment: Ciao Olivier! .